# Getting error while trying to create new directory into my project folder

Tags: node.js

```
// Getting error throw new Error(`Error creating log folder ${logFolder} - 
// ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
// Error: Error creating log folder ./logs/Pranjals-MacBook-Air.local -  
// {"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"mkdir","path":"./logs/Pranjals- 
// MacBook-Air.local"}

// I am trying to create new directory if do not exists but it's throwing 
// me the error

let logFolder = `./logs/${os.hostname()}`;

if (!fs.existsSync(logFolder)) {
    try {
        fs.mkdirSync(logFolder);
    } catch(e) {
        throw new Error(`Error creating log folder ${logFolder} - ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your '.logs' folder exists ?

Comment: @sparw logs folder do not exists and I need to create the folder along with the file inside it, if do not exists.

Answer (score 0):

To create directories recursively, I'm using [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) package.

Here is an example :

```
/**
 * CREATE DIR SYNC
 * Used to create a directory
 * @param {String} path
 */
let createDirSync = function (path = '') {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
        mkdirp.sync(path);
    }
};

createDirSync('/path/to/create/');
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to @Sparw's answer, you could do it without using a library. [`nodejs v10.x`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_mkdir_path_options) with the recursive option set to true.

```
let logFolder = `./logs/${os.hostname()}`;

if (!fs.existsSync(logFolder)) {
    try {
        await fs.promises.mkdir(logFolder, { recursive: true }) //or fs.mkdirSync(logFolder, { recursive: true })
    } catch(e) {
        throw new Error(`Error creating log folder ${logFolder} - ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// I simply added '{recursive:true}' property as second parameter
   and it worked fine for me

```
let logFolder = `logs/${os.hostname()}`;

if (!fs.existsSync(logFolder)) {
    try {
       fs.mkdirSync(logFolder, { recursive: true })
    } catch(e) {
        throw new Error(`Error creating log folder ${logFolder} - ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: By-default recursive value is set to false which means that the parent folder already exists and in my case 'logs' is the parent folder. By setting its value to true we include log folder to be created.